# what is the target file for otool -L at detecting non-public API in my xcode project

Tags: file, otool

I'm searching how to use otool for detecting non-public API in my xcode project. I know that should use otool in terminal. But it shows 'can't map file: appname.app (Invalid argument)' when I use otool -L.

I think the target file for otool is wrong, right?
used xxx.app file.

please help me.
thank u for ur attention.

Comment: I tried "otool -L libmediainfo.dylib" and it's showing the path information of it.

Answer (score 0):

otool is used for object files (xxx.0), library files (xxx.a) and others. But not for linked executables.

You can find non-public API utilizing [AppScanner](https://github.com/ChimpStudios/App-Scanner) on **xxx.app** file